# Recommended Exercise Lists for Quotient Objects

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, quotient-spaces, quotient-group, quotient-set

I *understand* the different types of quotient objects, but I still struggle with them - which I think is a result of me neglecting to work on them despite knowing it's a weak area of mine. How I generally learn about a concept in math is by solving more difficult problems about or using that concept. So my question is simply this.

Are there any good exercise lists for **difficult problems** dealing with quotient groups, rings, spaces, modules, sets, algebras or lie groups, etc, etc.

Comment: what kind of quotient do you mean? there are a lot out there, quotient by an action, or by a subobject? then finally, what category are you considering? an abelian one? or more a topological one?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, my fault for using the word object. I only mean it in a general algebraic sense, not categorically. So for example by quotient ring I mean the quotient of a ring by one of its ideals. But I want to add that I would also like any category theory problems regarding both quotients by actions and subobjects in any category.

Comment: I don't agree that it is a good way to view at quotients in a more general context (categories, topology etc.) if you still struggle with it. I would think that one first should take, say, a *quotient group* or *quotient ring* with many examples so that every detail is completely clear and one can do such examples quickly. With this experience the feeling of a "struggle" will disappear quickly and one can proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Let me propose a way of thinking about quotients a bit differently and you can distill some exercises from this post.

Let's stick to the group case, although much of these ideas extend beyond groups. Given a group $G$ and a normal subgroup $H\subseteq G$ one can define the quotient group $G/H$. As a set $G/H$ is just the collection of left $H$-cosests. The group operation is then simply defined by $gH\cdot g'H=gg'H$. You can verify that $H$ needs to be a normal subgroup for $G/H$ to be a group.

Okay, that's straightforward enough although it might not immediately be clear why this is important so let's view things differently. Given a surjective morphism $f\colon G\to C$ of groups, one has that $\ker(f)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $C\cong G/\ker(f)$. So quotients really just boil down to surjective maps.

Now look at surjection $f\colon G\to C$ and think about $C$. Clearly $C$ can be generated by some collection of elements of the form $f(g)$ and relations that hold in $G$ can be pushed to $C$. For example if $g^2=1$ for some $g$, then $f(g)^2=f(g^2)=1$ in $C$ as well. Of course $f$ can induce even more relations, for example $f(g)$ could be $1$ to begin with which is a stronger relation than $f(g)^2=1$. These additional relations are controlled by $\ker(f)$. So now we have a very powerful way of thinking about $C$. You can think of $C$ as just $G$ with a bunch of additional relations which are determined by $\ker(f)$. In a way, you can think of $C$ as a dumbed-down version of $G$ which, depending on how much information you killed, still contains some information on $G$. **(Edit: See [presentations of groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group)).**

Often a given group is too complicated to study directly, so one can impose extra relations and try to distill information from this quotient. For example, given a group $G$, the center $Z(G)$ is a normal subgroup. If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is commutative. As a corollary one finds that any group of order $p^2$ (with $p$ prime) is abelian. So here general nonsense on quotients yields a very concrete tool for studying groups.

Now the amount of useful exercises and applications on just quotients is somewhat limited but the idea of breaking up a structure into easier parts can be pushed further. I suggest you look at solvable groups and nilpotent groups were one considers a group $G$ together with a chain 
$$\{1\}=G_0\subseteq G_1\subseteq \dots \subseteq G_n=G$$ satisfying several conditions on the quotients $G_{i+1}/G_i$. There are many good exercises on these type of groups (for example: If $N\subseteq G$ is a normal subgroup, then $G$ is solvable if and only if both $N$ and $G/N$ are solvable). Solvable and nilpotent Lie algebra are defined in a similar manner and satisfy similar properties.

If you are capable of proving these types of result with ease, I think you are fairly comfortable working with quotients.